# Parte da mensagem de redireccionamento está em inglês

Tags: bug, internacionalização

Estava autenticado no **StackOverflow** e, depois que entrei no **StackOverflow em Português** e cliquei em **log-in**, apareceu rapidamente uma mensagem, no topo da janela, a avisar que eu estava a ser transferido da etapa de login para a tela de **Principais perguntas**. O problema é que parte desta mensagem estava em inglês e o restante em português.

```
Welcome back, nome_de_utilizador. You've been logged in.
Você está sendo redirecionado.
```